# Can I use "didn't" with "had" by reframing a sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

''Thank You' to everyone. I didn't have the time to reply. '

This sentence is obviously correct. But can I reframe it in the following way ?

''Thank You' to everyone I didn't had the time to reply to.'

(Ignore the essence of the sentence. The meaning remains the same in the original context.)

Comment: No, you can't. It's _I didn't have the time_ or _I hadn't the time_.

Comment: @KateBunting However you could say "I had not the time" if you didn't mind sounding old fashioned or "I had insufficient time."

Answer (score 5):

The auxiliary *do*, in all its forms ("do", "does", "did", "don't", "doesn't", "didn't") is **always** followed by the base form of the main verb. So "didn't had" is **never** grammatical.

"'Thank You' to everyone I didn't have the time to reply to." is perfectly good,  but I'm not sure if you're actually asking about "had" or about the final "to" or whether you think they are somehow connected.

Comment: Nah I was asking about the 'had' and you helped … Thanks … !!!